# How do I extract the path back out from a brush?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to convert a brush back to its underlying path, in Illustrator?

I want to edit a brush, make some small adjustments, and then convert it back to another brush.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Brush Palette, drag the brush to the artboard. You may need to release the clipping mask and/or ungroup to edit it.

[image]